# Why is my inherited class not hiding my base class method?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, polymorphism, autofac

I have a project which uses Autofac to instantiate the objects

```
builder.RegisterType<AbcWebWorkContext>().As<IWorkContext>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
```

This `AbcWebWorkContext` is a subclass of `WebWorkContext`:

```
public partial class AbcWebWorkContext : WebWorkContext
```

In my `AbcWebWorkContext` I would like to hide a method and a property from the parent class

```
protected new Customer GetCurrentCustomer(){ //do stuff }
new public Customer CurrentCustomer { //do studd }
```

But when someone calls

```
_workContext.CurrentCustomer
```

The base class property is called. If I call it like this

```
((AbcWebWorkContext) _workContext).CurrentCustomer
```

it works.

I would like to know why I am not able to hide the parent method.
I can't change the called class because it is in `NopCommerce`'s core, which I would not like to change.

Why is it not hiding the method?

Base class declaration of the methods:

```
protected Customer GetCurrentCustomer() { // do stuff }
public Customer CurrentCustomer{ // do stuff }
```

calling `GetType()` on `_workcontext` will output

> `{Name = "AbcWebWorkContext" FullName = "Nop.Web.Framework.AbcWebWorkContext"}`

The type hierarchy is `IWorkContext` (interface) « `WebWorkContext` « `AbcWebWorkContext`

`_workContext` is declared as `IWorkContext` and Autofac generates an instance as `AbcWebWorkContext` (as shown above)

Comment: How was the method declared in the base class?

Comment: @pickypg added it to the question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853896/is-it-possible-to-override-a-non-virtual-method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`new`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51y09td4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx#vclrfnew_newmodifier) keyword means that the subclass's method **hides** the baseclass's `CurrentCustomer` instead of overriding, so `WebWorkContext.CurrentCustomer` is a completely different method than `AbcWebWorkContext.CurrentCustomer`.

You must declare the base class's method as

```
virtual Customer CurrentCustomer { ... }
```

And the subclass's method

```
override Customer CurrentCustomer { ... }
```

I suggest you read more about [polymorphism in c#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

If the methods you're using are actually defined in an interface, `IWebWorkContext`, you simply encapsulate the base class rather than inheriting from it, like this:

```
class AbcWebWorkContext : IWebWorkContext
{
    private WebWorkerContext _inner = new WebWorkerContext();

    public Customer CurrentCustomer { ... }
}
```

If you can't make the base class's method virtual, you have to do something much less elegant, like reflection:

```
var prop = _workContext.GetType().GetProperty("CurrentCustomer");
var value = (Customer)prop.GetValue(_workContext, new object[0]);
```

Comment: I can't because I can't change the core source code.
calling gettype() in _workcontext will output 
{Name = "AbcWebWorkContext" FullName = "Nop.Web.Framework.AbcWebWorkContext"}. So AbcWebWorkContext version of the method should be called. right?

Comment: Sorry, I do not own neither the caller code nor the callee code. I am trying to intercept the call to make changes to its behavior without changing the core's code.

Comment: @Oscar Then I'm afraid re-implementing the interface is probably your only option.

Comment: =/ that is bad. I will ask directly in nopcommerce's forum to check if there is any other point in the system that I could plugin the piece of code I want. Thanks :)

Comment: Marking as answer due to the help to get to a conclusion that it is not possible to do what I would like to accomplish the way I want to

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I got your questions right, but I think you need to add a `virtual` modifier to the method in base class and add a `override` modifier to method in the subclass.

Find out more on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4.aspx)

Comment: Yes, that would be overriding the method, but I can't add "virtual" because I cant change the source code

Comment: @Oscar, C# is not like Java, methods are not virtual by default. If you cannot modify the base class to make the method virtual, you cannot override it in the child class. You have the option of *hiding* it, but as you have found, it's not that useful except via the derived class' own reference.

Comment: Yes, my bad. I wrote "override" in the title of this question. I meant hide. I will edit it. calling gettype() in _workcontext will output {Name = "AbcWebWorkContext" FullName = "Nop.Web.Framework.AbcWebWorkContext"}. So AbcWebWorkContext version of the method should be called. right?

Comment: @Oscar note it *is* actually hiding the base class method. This is how hidden methods are supposed to work.

Comment: @p.s.w.g sorry, I didn't get. If it is hiding the base class method, why would the base class method be called instead of the child class?

Comment: @Oscar I guess that's because your `_workContext` is declared as a base class instance

Comment: @Oscar it's hiding the base class's method when calling `AbcWebWorkContext.CurrentCustomer`, the base class's method still exist and is publicly accessible as `WebWorkContext.CurrentCustomer`. So in essence it subclass has two methods, and one is just "hidden".

Comment: @Terry not, it is not, I've updated the question. It is declared as IWorkCotext

Comment: @p.s.w.g yes, sorry I didn't mentioned it before, is it declared as IWorkContext. Please check the update I just made in the question

Comment: @Oscar That does give you some more options. Please see my updated answer for information on encapsulating the base class.