# Override ListView Clear() method

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a `ListView` class that uses the `ItemSelectionChanged` event to maintain its own list of selected items.

This is working well, except that `Clear()` doesn't seem to fire the `ItemSelectionChanged` event.
This means that after `Clear()` is called the list still contains all of the items that were highlighted prior to `Clear()` being called.

I wanted to override the `Clear()` method so that I could clear the list myself, but I can see that it's not marked as virtual. Is there another way that I can use the existing `Clear()` method?

Plan B is that I just write my own method and call it right after clear, but that isn't as nice.

```
listView1.Clear();
listView1.ClearMyList();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

actually I dont know the name of this feature of c# (**public new void**), but you can do this by creating your own "customListView".

```
var listView = new CustomListView();
listView.Clear();

public class CustomListView : ListView
{
    public new void Clear()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I can clear myself...");
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: inheritance is the name

Comment: I'm referring to the "public new void", is this also inheritance?

Comment: nop, this is hidding: *[The **new** modifier creates a new member with the same name and causes the original member to become hidden.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx)*

Answer (score 0):

You can not override non virtual method. So writting your 'new' own method is the best way to go.

[This is a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853896/is-it-possible-to-override-a-non-virtual-method)