# C# function override

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, polymorphism, overriding, vuforia

I use vuforia sdk to track 2d marker. Now I can handle marker detection and lost. Vuforia sdk has a .cs file. The content of it :

```
namespace Vuforia
{
    public class DefaultTrackableEventHandler : MonoBehaviour,
                                                ITrackableEventHandler
    {
        private TrackableBehaviour mTrackableBehaviour;
        void Start()
        { ... }

        public void OnTrackableStateChanged(
                                        TrackableBehaviour.Status previousStatus,
                                        TrackableBehaviour.Status newStatus)
        {
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

I try to override `OnTrackableStateChanged` function. So I create a new .cs file.

```
public class ImageTargetScript : DefaultTrackableEventHandler {
     public void OnTrackableStateChanged(
                                            TrackableBehaviour.Status previousStatus,
                                            TrackableBehaviour.Status newStatus)
    {
         Debug.Log("**OVERRIDE FUNCTION**");
    }
}
```

I drag my new .cs file to game object. When I run this code on unity, I don't see output text as "OVERRIDE FUNCTION".

What is my fault? How can I override this function?

.

Comment: OnTrackableStateChanged isnt virtual so you [can't override it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853896/is-it-possible-to-override-a-non-virtual-method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `OnTrackableStateChanged` in the base class should be marked `virtual`, so it can be overridden (now it can't, and you should see a warning about this in your IDE). The override method should have the `override` keyword in it:

```
public virtual void OnTrackableStateChanged(...) { }

public override void OnTrackableStateChanged(...) { }
```

Comment: You could add [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853896/is-it-possible-to-override-a-non-virtual-method) to your answer so OP dont need to ask if there is a way around ;)

Comment: Does OP know what those keywords mean? I think that question is already a step further in the process.

Comment: This example donesn't has a virtual keyword http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_polymorphism.html

Comment: Indeed, so drop it from your list as a useful tutorial.

Comment: If you would read a bit further your tutorial says `Only if a method is declared virtual, derived classes can override this method if they are explicitly declared to override the virtual base class method with the override keyword.`

Comment: True, but the sample should follow that. The program doesn't give the desired behavior now and it introduces compiler warnings. @Nitro.de