# OData v8 - Request Header Versioning

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger, odata, asp.net5

I am trying to get versioning to work via the request header in .NET 5 using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData v8.0.1 and versioning to work with SwaggerUI.

Pre-v8, you used to be able to use

```
services.AddODataApiExplorer(...);
```

which would enable DependencyInjection for the Startup's Configure method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IApiVersionDescriptionProvider provider) {
    ...
    app.UseSwagger();

    app.UseSwaggerUI(options => {
        // build a swagger endpoint for each discovered API version
        foreach (var description in provider.ApiVersionDescriptions) {
                    
            options.SwaggerEndpoint($"/swagger/{description.GroupName}/swagger.json", description.GroupName.ToUpperInvariant());
        }
        options.ShowExtensions();
    });
    ...
}
```

OData8 appears to not handle this out of the box and the [best documentation I can find on versioning](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/api-versioning-extension-with-asp-net-core-odata-8/) only handles URL Segment and hints at Query String versioning. I'd prefer to save characters in the URL if I can which is why I want to go with Request Header versioning.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: You can add a header parameter to all versioned actions using an operation filter. It would show up in the swagger ui. Would that work for you?

Comment: Like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68101038/custom-operation-ids-for-single-document-and-not-the-other/68176836#68176836 but as a header, not query parameter. See the header `Setting default parameters depending on version in Swagger UI`

Answer (score 1):

So, instead of using

`services.AddODataApiExplorer(...);`

you can use

`services.AddApiVersioning(...);`

It won't (currently) get picked up properly by the SwaggerUI but it will generate the client code properly and respond to versioning by routing to the target versioned controller.

I was able to find the most clear and concise documentation on versioning in the article, '[REST API versioning with ASP.NET Core](https://dev.to/99darshan/restful-web-api-versioning-with-asp-net-core-1e8g)'

Answer (score 0):

//WHEN VERSIONING BY: query string, **header**, or media type

```
  endpoints.MapVersionedODataRoute( "odata", "api", modelBuilder );
```

//WHEN VERSIONING BY: url segment

```
endpoints.MapVersionedODataRoute( "odata-bypath", "api/v{version:apiVersion}", modelBuilder );
```

Comment: Also, take a look this article https://dev.to/99darshan/restful-web-api-versioning-with-asp-net-core-1e8g