# What does the "new" operator mean in the context of inside an Interface?

Tags: c#

I have the runtime code from `IEnumerable` interface below:

```
public partial interface IEnumerable
{
    System.Collections.IEnumerator GetEnumerator();
}
```

and then

```
public partial interface IEnumerable<out T> : System.Collections.IEnumerable
{
    new System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator();
}
```

What is the meaning of the "new" on the second partial interface. Notice that that is an interface, there is no instance being created there because it is not an implementation, it must mean something else.

Edit:
By the way the second if for generics only, the first one is the "object" `IEnumerable`.

Comment: That's the keyword used to shadow a member - meaning that this `interface` is redefining the `GetEnumerator()` of the parent `interface`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583104/what-does-new-keyword-mean-when-used-inside-an-interface-in-c