# List all usages of keyword "new"

Tags: c#

I thought the keyword "new" in C# was only use to instantiate a class. Lately I discovered it can also hide inheritance. So are there any cases where you would use it?

Comment: Is the question about get all usages of `new` within VS or when to use `new` to hide an inherited member? In the latter case this is a diplucate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576206/what-is-the-difference-between-the-override-and-new-keywords-in-c

Comment: What part of the documentation is unclear?..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why would you want to hide a method using \`new\`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184294/why-would-you-want-to-hide-a-method-using-new)

Comment: The question is to list all usages of keyword "new" in a topic. MSDN documentation already answer this question though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can look at the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51y09td4.aspx):

> In C#, the new keyword can be used as an operator, a modifier, or a
>   constraint.
>
> **[new Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fa0ab757.aspx)**
>
> Used to create objects and invoke constructors.
>
> **[new Modifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx)**
>
> Used to hide an inherited member from a base class member.
>
> **[new Constraint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx)**
>
> Used to restrict types that might be used as arguments for a type
>   parameter in a generic declaration.

Answer (score 4):

In C#, the new keyword can be used as an operator, a modifier, or a constraint.

> - [new Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fa0ab757.aspx): Used to create objects and invoke constructors.
> - [new Modifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx): Used to hide an inherited member from a base class member.
> - [new Constraint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx): Used to restrict types that might be used as arguments for a type parameter in a generic declaration.

Source: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51y09td4.aspx)

Comment: Please reference the [source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51y09td4.aspx).

Comment: I think @MikeEason means you should reference the page you copy/pasted your answer from. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34672801/1364007) for what would be better: (a) a link to the original page, (b) quote formatting (yellow background) so it's clear they didn't write it.

Comment: I just completed the full answer