# Understanding Virtual Methods, Method Hiding, and Overriding in C#

Tags: c#, oop

I've read through a few tutorials (including the ones on the MSDN website) about Method Hiding and Overriding in C# and I ran across a problem in a snippet of code I wrote while trying to understand the logic:

```
class A
{
    public virtual void Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A");
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public override void Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B");
    }
}

class C : B
{
    new public virtual void Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("C");
    }
}
```

```
class Driver
{
    static void Main()
    {
        A a = new A();
        a.Foo();
        B b = new B();
        b.Foo();
        C c = new C();
        c.Foo();
        a = new B();
        a.Foo();
        a = new C();
        a.Foo();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Whenever I run that code I get this output:
A
B
C
B
B

I understand the first four, but shouldn't the fifth output be 'C' because the run-time instance is C and not A? I'm not very comfortable yet with method hiding but shouldn't declaring "new public virtual void Foo()" in class C allow that Foo() to be called instead of the one from B?

Comment: I don't think you can use `new` and `virtual` at the same time.  `virtual` means you're overriding; `new` means you are shadowing.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I didn't think so, either; maybe it just gives a warning? Though to Zach; that's what hiding does, essentially.

Comment: You have read about method overriding and hiding. The last case is hiding. Doesn't that make sense?

Comment: @RobertHarvey, its `new` and `override`, that can't be used together, `new` and `virtual` can be used together

Comment: So `new` `virtual` means that you are shadowing, but you can override the shadowed method later?  Sounds confusing to me, and I've never seen anyone actually do this.

Comment: Please reopen if this duplicate question does not answer yours. I think it does.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415900/what-is-public-new-virtual-void-method-mean and yes it is weird.

Comment: Thanks usr, the duplicate question answered my question perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Fifth output is `B`, because you're looking at `C` instance as if it was `A` instance, so that's where you're method dispatch begin.

From `A.Foo` it goes up the inheritance chain, checks `B.Foo` and `C.Foo`. Because `C.Foo` is marked with `new` modifier, `B.Foo` is the one that is actually called.

You'd get `C` as output for following snippet:

```
C c = new C();
c.Foo();
```

Comment: The fifth output isn't C - it's B, the same as you'd have by doing `A instance = new C();`

Comment: @DanielMay Of course, you're right. Just a typo.