# c# 6 bug? virtual new method strange behavior

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
using System;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Foo foo = new Foo();
            Bar bar = new Bar();
            Baz baz = new Baz();
            Foo fooBar = new Bar();
            Foo fooBaz = new Baz();
            Bar barBaz = new Baz();

            foo.Test();
            bar.Test();
            baz.Test();
            fooBar.Test();
            fooBaz.Test();
            barBaz.Test();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    internal class Foo
    {
        public virtual void Test()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Foo");
        }
    }

    internal class Bar : Foo
    {
        public new virtual void Test()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Bar");
        }
    }

    internal class Baz : Bar
    {
        public override void Test()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Baz");
        }
    }
}
```

it outputs me:

```
Foo
Bar
Baz
Foo
Foo
Baz
```

But, I thought it should be:

```
Foo
Bar
Baz
Foo
Baz
Baz
```

Because Baz is overriding the method. What is happening here?
Am I missing something? Why did the output for fooBaz.Test() is "Foo" instead of "Baz"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Buz` is overriding the method, that's why

```
Bar barBaz = new Baz();
barBaz.Test();
```

will print `Baz`.

But `Bar` is not overriding - it is *hiding* the base method `Test` and makes the new method virtual. Then `Baz` is overriding the new method from `Bar`, not the method from `Foo`.
So if you reference it like this: `Foo fooBaz = new Baz();` then `fooBaz` is treated like an instance of `Foo`, which has no idea of the hiding method.

The output that you're expecting would be generated if you changed `public new virtual void Test()` to `public override void Test()`.

See also these topics:

- [new keyword in method signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014295/new-keyword-in-method-signature)
- [what is "public new virtual void Method()" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415900/what-is-public-new-virtual-void-method-mean)
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx

Comment: exactly, Baz is overriding the method. Baz should be considered first by the compiler, shouldn't it?

Comment: Jon Skeet should explain this one, because I still don't get it, hahahah

Answer (score 2):

When you use the new keyword on `Bar.Test` you're saying it has no relation to `Foo.Test` other than that it has the same name. Since Baz inherits from Bar, it overrides `Bar.Test` but leaves `Foo.Test` unmodified.

When you call `fooBaz.Test` it looks up the unmodified `Foo.Test` method and prints "Foo".

When you call `barBaz.Test` it looks up the overriden `Bar.Test` method and prints "Baz".