# Overriding and Hiding methods in C #

Tags: polymorphism, overriding, method-hiding

Suppose we have defined two classes (A and B):

```
class A
{
    public new virtual string ToString()
    {
        return "I'm class A object.";
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "I'm class B object.";
    }
}
```

If we write:

```
A a = new B();
Console.WriteLine(a);
```

"B" (`namespace.B`) will be displayed in the console.
That is, the ToString() method of an implicit ancestor of Class A (System.Object.ToString()) will be called.

Why is calling a method of the System.Object class, not class A or B?

Comment: Can help this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415900/what-is-public-new-virtual-void-method-mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, if you do this:

```
Console.WriteLine(a.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(b.ToString());
```

It writes out the two strings you want.

The new means you have to explicitly call `ToString` from an `A` instance. Hence `a.ToString()` works.  `((object)a).ToString()` does not.

By calling `Console.WriteLine(a)`, you are calling the `Console.Writeline(object)` overload.  As a result the `WriteLine` function is making use of an `object` reference therefore you get the default `object.ToString()`.

Make it override in both cases and the problem goes away (i'm guessing you already know this):

```
class A
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "I'm class A object.";
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "I'm class B object.";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I've really lost sight of the call to the overloaded Console.WriteLine(Object) method. This is the reason that the Object's ToString() method was called.