# calling base method using new keyword

Tags: c#, methods, new-operator, keyword

in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014295/c-sharp-new-keyword-in-method-signature), they have this code:

```
public class Base
{
   public virtual void Method(){}
}

public class Derived : Base
{
   public new void Method(){}
}
```

and then called like this:

```
Base b = new Derived();
b.Method();
```

my actual code is this:

```
public class Base
{
   public void Method()
   {
        // bla bla bla
   }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
   public new void Method()
   {
        base.Method();
   }
}
```

is it necessary to call with `base.Method();` ?
or just leave the method in derived class blank ?

Comment: Good question.  This tends to get missed in most of the online helps regarding derivations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need 'base' if you really need to call the base class's method. 
 `base.Method();` is the correct way.

[Knowing When to Use Override and New Keywords (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/knowing-when-to-use-override-and-new-keywords)

Comment: Old link. Report a summary please: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/knowing-when-to-use-override-and-new-keywords