# Why does a public non-virtual member of a superclass interfering with overriding in a subclass

Tags: c#, overriding, virtual-functions

What is a design rationale behind this:

OK:

```
public class A
{
    public virtual void DoWork() { Console.WriteLine("A"); }
}
public class B : A
{
    private new void DoWork() { Console.WriteLine("B"); } //private works
}
public class C : B
{
    public override void DoWork() { Console.WriteLine("C"); }
}
```

WRONG:

```
public class A
{
    public virtual void DoWork() { Console.WriteLine("A"); }
}
public class B : A
{
    public new void DoWork() { Console.WriteLine("B"); } //public doesn't
}
public class C : B
{
    public override void DoWork() { Console.WriteLine("C"); }
}
```

Why does non-virtual method interfere with overriding virtual method anyway?

1st case: compiler checks that the method is private (new) so it allows class C.DoWork() to override class A.DoWork() (does not mix virtual and not-virtual (B.DoWork()) methods).

2nd case: compiler sees that public (new) void is declared and it arbitrarily(?) disrupts overriding in class C.

Now, if I wanted to declare new virtual DoWork() I could have done it, if I wanted to disallow overriding, I could have used sealed specifier. But in this case I wrote public void DoWork() as declaring normal non-virtual method and I do not expect it participating in virtual inheritance chain as in the private case. In 2nd example I expect:

```
A ac = new C();
ac.DoWork();
```

to print C as in the private case.

Answer (score 0):

In first example your `C` class ovverides A's `DoWork` (`B` had DoWork, which is private and not visible to subclasses). In second example you hide `DoWork` by non-virtual function and compiler complains, that you are trying to override non-virtual function. Solution is to  expose families of virtual functions. By `new virtual` you can create separations between these families.

```
public class B : A
{
    public new virtual void DoWork() { Console.WriteLine("B"); } //private works
}
```

This code then

```
A a = new C();
a.DoWork();
```

prints `A`

```
B b = new C();
b.DoWork();
```

prints `C`

You can read in more detail how `new virtual` is used in [Knowing When to Use Override and New Keywords](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173153%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). `new` keyword without `virtual` has a different semantics from `new virtual`, you can read more about it at [new keyword in method signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014295/new-keyword-in-method-signature).

Comment: You are missing that there is NO virtual specified inside middle (B) class. Yes, new virtual in C# unlike C++ ends the chain of virtual dispatch, but in this case b.DoWork() is not virtual at all.

Comment: So the base class has `virtual` keyword so `DoWork` is virtual and can't be hidden in subclasses without `virtual` specifier.

Answer (score 0):

Because in *first* case you're overriding an `A` class function and not `B` one

```
public class A
{
    public virtual void DoWork() { Console.WriteLine("A"); }
}
public class B : A
{
    private new void DoWork() { Console.WriteLine("B"); } //private works
}
public class C : B
{
    public override void DoWork() { Console.WriteLine("C"); } //OVERRIDES A.DoWork()
}
```

You *can not* override **non** `virtual`/`abstract` methods of the base class.

Answer (score 0):

In below code

```
public class A
{
    public virtual void DoWork() { Console.WriteLine("A"); }
}
public class B : A
{
    private new void DoWork() { Console.WriteLine("B"); } //private works
}
public class C : B
{
    public override void DoWork() { Console.WriteLine("C"); }
}
```

you are telling the compiler that DoWork() method in B class is a `new` version of class A's DoWork() method. However, it allows you to `override` DoWork in C due to the fact that you have declared DoWork's `new` version as private in B which makes the compiler assume that that method is not exposed to the outside world.

However, in this,

```
public class A
{
    public virtual void DoWork() { Console.WriteLine("A"); }
}
public class B : A
{
    public new void DoWork() { Console.WriteLine("B"); } //public
}
public class C : B
{
    public override void DoWork() { Console.WriteLine("C"); }
}
```

You are telling the compiler to `override` new version of method DoWork(), which is a bit wrong from compiler's point of view as it cannot `override` a non `abstract`/`virtual`/`overriden` method as per the rules set while designing the language.

That is why, I think, your code gives error in one case and not the other.