# Is assigning a List<int> to IEnumerable<int> beneficial or not?

Tags: c#

The language I use is C#.

Say that a method of an object returns a `List<int>`. If we assign this result to a variable of type `IEnumerable<int>` would we benefit anything or not?

In other words

```
IEnumerable<int> result = list
```

is better than

`List<int> result = list`,

where `list` is a `List<int>`.

I think intuitively that we will not benefit anything. However, i would like to be sure. Hence I am asking this.

Comment: List has functionality that IEnumerable does not. If you need this functionality, return List.  Otherwise, return IEnumerable such that in future if any changes are done, it won't be a chain reaction of refactoring.

Comment: Yes, but return IList<T> instead of List<T>.

Comment: @bland, so the only benefit I will have it will letter if I do a refactor of my existing code. In terms of optimization, I will not gain anything, If I got you. Right?

Comment: Correct, there is no optimization in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drawback is that you won't be able to use `List<T>` specific methods.
The benefit is that you will be able to change the implementation in the method that returns the list to another kind of list (or set or ...) because the only thing you require is `IEnumerable<T>`.

A compromise is `IList<T>` if you need methods like `Add`.

And also, it is not a good idea to return `List<T>` from a method. If you are the implementer of the method, then you should at least return `IList<T>` or maybe even `IEnumerable<T>`.

In general there are circumstances where you *have to* cast to a base type, see [new keyword in method signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014295/new-keyword-in-method-signature).

Comment: no I don't want any methods like Add. The only thing I want in my case is to use a foreach statement to go over all elements of the list.

Comment: @ChristosPaisios Then I see no reason why you shouldn't just use `IEnumerable<T>`. Another option is to use `var`, but only do that if it is clear what type the method returns.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason you would do this, is to return your list to a caller, in such a way, that the caller wouldn't be able to modify the list*.

**unless the caller performed a hard cast on the list*

That said - it's always beneficial to use the least specific class/interface possible - as it opens up more possibilities for code reuse.

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case there is no reason to type the local variable as the interface.  If the object implemented some interface explicitly, then you may want to do this, but that's not the case for `List` and `IEnumerable`.  It implements `IEnumerable<T>` *explicitly*.

If you consider it likely that you'll be wanting to set something else to `result` that is an `IEnumerable` and not a `List` then you could do this, but generally I wouldn't bother to make such a change unless you're actually in that situation, rather than trying to do it preemtively.  Being a local variable, rather than say part of the public API of a type, you'd always be able to change the type of the variable in a future revision without any real significant consequences.